# bada Programming - Popup message with Keypad

Tags: c++, popup, bada, keypad

I have this error where I click something, it will popup a message with a close button, when I click on the close button, some part of the popup does not close properly. Here is a screen shot of it. May I know how to solve this?

this is the popup:

[image]

this is the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to call a requestredraw on the form, which will refresh the complete form

Comment: Hi, I tried doing requestredraw, in the method onActionPerformed. The thing is I am doing on tabs with panels, I have no idea if trying requestredraw in onActionPerformed is right or wrong. :/

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for all the suggestions. I have decided to make it simpler by using the messageBox instead. Thank you for contributing your suggestions and your precious time :)

Comment: @Winona please note that if you use the `MessageBox` class in the Bada SDK, then your app may get rejected. More info here: http://forums.badadev.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1339

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a refresh problem to me. Try to call `Show()` or `Draw()` on the keypad object to force a refresh.

Comment: Hi, it is really a refresh problem, but however Show() and Draw() doesn't work.

Comment: @Winona: Have you seen this in another app? A message box above the keypad? Maybe this is bad UI design... Maybe you should give other feedback to the user, like a red background and show the message box only if the user submits the form and the keypad is not visible. Or simply remove the keypad, show your message, display the keypad again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding! Yes, I have tried removing the keypad, show the message then display the keypad again. The problem is, I have 2 editfields, let's say at editfield2, the message pops up, then i click close and the keypad will popup for editfield1 and not back to editfield2. :/

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for all the suggestions. I have decided to make it simpler by using the messageBox instead. Thank you for contributing your suggestions and your precious time :)